# How can I save objects to files in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm running a Node server and I was wondering - how can I **serialize objects and write them to a file?**

Comment: You might want a DB instead, e.g. Couch, Mongo, MySQL.

Comment: Do you want to write a string (or bytes) to a file or do you want to save any object?

Comment: The question marked as duplicate **is not asking the same thing.** This question is really about *serialization* ***and*** writing to a file, not just writing to a file!

Comment: You edited your post; the original was not clear that you also meant serialization. In any case, it is still a duplicate; just of a different question, this time.

Comment: I looked at the question and it's younger than this one (asked in 2012)! Besides, the title is virtually the same as my own original title from 2011. Also it is asking a different thing, and the accepted answer is different as well. If I were to discover my question looking for serialization techniques I'd be confused.

Comment: The lack of consistency between the title and question itself is unfortunate, but this does appear to be the earliest question about serialization on SO that uses the word "serialize".  Seems reasonable to reopen.

Comment: @ConspiciousCompiler - how are they inconsistent? The title is more *general* maybe. But yes if that's the case it'd like to see it reopened :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use

```
var str = JSON.stringify(object)
```

to serialize your objects to a JSON string and

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string)
```

To read it back as an object. The string can be written to file. So, for example an object like this:

```
var p = new Foo();
p.Bar = "Terry"
var s = JSON.stringify(p)
// write s to file, get => { "Bar" : "Terry" }
// read s from file and turn back into an object:
var p = JSON.parse(s);
```

Writing and reading to/from files is covered here: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/fs.html#fs.write

Comment: you can also read-and-parse in one step by requiring a json file. e.g.  var p = require('savefile.json');

Comment: But this doesn't serialise any functions of the object.

Comment: I thought it was more proper for the answer to contain the solution rather than link to a solution.