# writing js objects to files (including methods) in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see how I can write objects to files as described here: [How can I save objects to files in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284849/how-can-i-save-objects-to-files-in-node-js) but is there a way to take an object and write it in a way that allows me to reload the object into memory including its methods?

Comment: Writing and reading functions presents a huge risk for injection.  I would consider the security implications of this decision.

Comment: I agree with Anthony. If you really need it, though, you can simply save the JavaScript code, then load it and call `eval` on it.

Comment: I agree on the security concerns. I'm just playing around with an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @AnthonySottile said before, this can be extremely dangerous and I'm not sure there is ever a good use case for it, but just for kicks and giggles you would need to write your own recursive serializer. Something like this:

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function dump_object(obj) {
    var buff, prop;
    buff = [];
    for (prop in obj) {
        buff.push(dump_to_string(prop) + ': ' + dump_to_string(obj[prop]))
    }
    return '{' + buff.join(', ') + '}';
}

function dump_array(arr) {
    var buff, i, len;
    buff = [];
    for (i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++) {
        buff.push(dump_to_string(arr[i]));
    }
    return '[' + buff.join(', ') + ']';
}

function dump_to_string(obj) {
    if (toString.call(obj) == '[object Function]') {
        return obj.toString();
    } else if (toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]') {
        return dump_array(obj);
    } else if (toString.call(obj) == '[object String]') {
        return '"' + obj.replace('"', '\\"') + '"';
    } else if (obj === Object(obj)) {
        return dump_object(obj);
    }
    return obj.toString();
}
```

This will handle most types, but there is always the chance of an oddball messing it up so **I would not use this in production**. Afterwards unserializing is as easy as:

```
eval('var test = ' + dump_to_string(obj))
```

Comment: O_O Why are you re-inventing the wheel? Define the `toJSON` method for custom serialization of an object, eg. `<SomeObject>.prototype.toJSON`. For even more flexibility, define a [replacer for `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Syntax).

Comment: @RobW Did not know about either of those. Very useful, Thanks!

Comment: dump_to_string the replace function for "'s has to be global, eg:
obj.replace(/\"/g, '\\"')
Supplied an edit but I think it got maybe rejected, dunno :)

Comment: Agree with @jaywink, `obj.replace` should be using `/"/g` to ensure all `"` get replaced correctly, not just the first one.

Comment: It's been 4 years since this answer was given, but it just saved me! You made my day! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite old, but I couldn't find anywhere some simple solution to the question of effective serialization in JavaScript.
One could use [BSON](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson) (MongoDB inner objects representation) which uses a binary format to represent objects in memory.

I could not find some link to the documentation, but the [code is well documented](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/dd196e24512a6677a6061e9baa610fee6bca9659/lib/bson/bson.js#L1475) and I came up with something like this :

```
fs = require 'fs'
bson = require('bson').BSONPure.BSON

obj = {
  string: "test",
  func: (s) ->
    console.log s
}

fs.writeFile 'test.txt', bson.serialize(obj, false, false, true), (err) ->
  return console.log("Err : #{err}") if err
  fs.readFile 'test.txt', (err, file) ->
    return console.log("Err : #{err}") if err
    deserialized = bson.deserialize file, evalFunctions: true
    deserialized.func deserialized.string // Outputs 'text', as expected
```

It is [coffee-script](http://coffeescript.org) but the code is simple enough for everyone to understand.

Comment: Careful with that 'evalFunctions: true' option since it will allow javascript execution (see https://gist.github.com/DinisCruz/245716893d783ea740ea)

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote shoveJS: https://shovemedia.github.io/shovejs/ to handle exactly this sort of thing. YMMV -- I haven't tried it with Node yet.

It converts a typed object structure to JSON (which you'd then save to disk) and can inflate that structure back into typed objects including proper object -> object references etc. To be clear, the method / class definitions themselves are NOT serialized. The system simply expects that registered Model / Factory classes available during serialization are also available during deserialization.

Apologies in advance for not having some simple examples posted.

edit: the technique is a souped-up take on what Rob W mentions in his comment below