# Node: Persist changes to an imported array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

In data.js, I have a big object array and a couple of functions:

```
var arr = [ {prop1: value, prop2: value},...]

function push (value) {
    arr.push(value);
}

function pop () {
    arr.pop()
}

module.exports.data = arr;
module.exports.push = push;
module.exports.pop = pop;
```

To load the array & functions in my app.js & test them, I use:

```
var mod = require('./data');

console.log(mod.arr.length); // outputs length prior to modification
arr.push(1);                  
console.log(mod.arr.length); // outputs length + 1
```

That's all fine while the server is running, but changes are never persisted to the data.js array. Do I have to read/write to a file or is there a simple way I can modify the imported array & save the changes?

Answer (score 1):

Thera a few popular ways to save you data:

1) Use files

2) Use redis

3) Use database (Mongodb or other)

Comment: I'd prefer to just use a simple js array in a js file. I've been using fs.methods as a workaround, but they work with plain text strings, not js arrays. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: pls see other topics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284849/how-can-i-save-objects-to-files-in-node-js

Comment: so I will have to write as plain text using the fs module after all :)